# filter blur afetando outras div

Tags: css, css3

como faço pro filter só afetar a div do fundo, no caso a `wrapper` e também como retirar aquela borda que ele poe? o objetivo é ofuscar apenas a imagem ta assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://blog.viajeglobal.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/toscana-italia-wallpaper_mini.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(10px);
 }

#chat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 64.28571428571429%;/*900*/
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="chat">chat</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver seu problema inicialmente separe os elementos, de modo que a div wrapper e chat estejam na mesma estrutura, não uma sendo elemento pai da outra. A partir disso você pode manipular sua posição alternando o z-index, isso já resolve seu primeiro problema. Para as bordas brancas aplicadas pelo efeito blur, acredito que manipular o background seja a melhor solução pois a cor herdada afeta a imagem, no exemplo abaixo utilizei a cor preto para simular o resultado.

```css
/* A borda branca vem do background da página, manipulando essa cor você consegue alterar */
body {
  background-color: black; 
}

#wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://blog.viajeglobal.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/toscana-italia-wallpaper_mini.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(10px);
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  z-index: 1;
 }

#chat {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 64.28571428571429%;/*900*/
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
  <div id="chat">chat</div>
</body>
```